# Can I put my 2.1" 29er tires on a wheel with 25mm inner diameter?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, wheels, ergonomics

So I broke my second front wheel last night when I hit a dip that rose too quickly for my wheel to climb before all my weight went behind it. I'm a big guy (300+ lbs), so my wheels need to be able to take a beating.

Right now I have a 2014 [Specialized Rockhopper Comp 29er](http://www.specialized.com/us/en/bikes/archive/2014/rockhopper/rockhopper-comp-29#specs) with the original fork, tires, and just about everything except the peddles and wheels. I upgraded to Mavic CrossOnes last year after I taco'ed the original front wheel on a hard turn.

I am getting tired of replacing these wheels. It is getting a bit expensive too. So I want to find some really tough rims and from what I read you need to get wheels that have a wider inner rim. The Mavics are 19mm if I remember correctly.

I am thinking about upgrading to a DT Swiss EX 471 29er rim which has a 25mm inner width. But I would like to stick with the ground control tires I already have and really like.

Would my 2.1" Ground Control tire work on this wider rim? I am also considering going tubeless. Also, any recommendations for stronger wheels for my heavy body?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I look for in a new front wheel for my heavy body?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32971/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-new-front-wheel-for-my-heavy-body)

Answer (score 1):

According the [Sheldon](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) need 25mm for a 2.1"

A downhill wheel tends to be strong (and heavier)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here's a [tire size to rim width chart](http://www.schwalbetires.com/tech_info/tire_dimensions#rim) from Schwalbe.